# Missing app roles in access token from AzureAD

Tags: vue.js, azure-active-directory, roles, azure-ad-msal

SPA app signs in the AzureAD and get the access token `api:api app id/acces_as_user`. However no roles are in the access token.

```
*created() {
    //this.$msal.signOut();    
     if (!this.$msal.isAuthenticated()) {        
       this.$msal.signIn();    
    }
    else{
      console.log(this.$msal)
      // get access token to webapi
      this.$msal
        .acquireToken({scopes: ["api://58ca819e-/access_as_user"]})
        .then((res)=>{
          console.log(res)
          auth.accessToken = res
        })
        .catch(err=>console.error(err))
    }
  },*
```

Any idea please?

My configuration:

AzureAD user has been assigned to role `admin` in api app:
[image]

SPA client (Vue): configured to `azure ad client app`

```
Vue.use(msal, {
  auth: {
    clientId: 'be7e77ba-',
    tenantId: '3a0cf09b-',
    redirectUri: appInfo.redirectUri,
    autoRefreshToken: true,
  },   
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
  },
});
```

ASPNET Core WebAPI: confiured to `azure ad api app`

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "58ca819e-",
    "TenantId": "3a0cf09b-"
  },
```

AzureAD client app: has a permission to api app `api:api app id/acces_as_user`

API Permissions:
[image]

AzureAD api app: has scope `api:api app id/acces_as_user`, app role `admin`, token configuration to include groups as roles.
Token Configuration:

[image]

App roles:

[image]

Expose an API:

[image]

Comment: Looks like the configuration is correct. Are you sure you are using the correct account which has been assigned `admin` app role? And if you decode the access token in https://jwt.io/, does it contain the correct `scp` claim?

Comment: access token has `scp: access_as_user` which allows me to access webapi but no roles appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you select **Emit groups as role claims**, which covers your app roles.

If you want to get Group claims together with the app roles, unselect **Emit groups as role claims** and [configure `"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"` in the manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims#configure-the-azure-ad-application-registration-for-group-attributes).

Comment: Thank you. It worked when i uncheck "Emit groups as role claims". `roles:[admin]` is still generated in the access token even I delete `group claims` in `Token configuration`. Any idea?

Comment: @beewest Yes. Deleting `group claims` in `Token configuration` doesn't effect on app roles. It's expected.